# Convert multiple files types (pdf, jpg, png or txt ) in folder to PDF - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to print all documents inside a folder (whether they are PDF, JPG, PNG or TXT), but all I can read about is how to convert/print specific files types to PDF.

Is it possible to have a macro to print all the PDF, JPG, PNG or TXT files inside a folder?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should helps

```
Sub printf()
TargetFolder = "c:\test\"
If TargetFolder > "" Then
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(TargetFolder)
  Set colItems = objFolder.Items
  For Each objItem In colItems
    objItem.InvokeVerbEx ("Print")

  Next
 msgbox "All files in folders being printed"
else
  msgbox "Please specify a folder name"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do `c:\test\` folder contains any files? Do you enable macros? Do you add references? Do you have printer installed? Default printer is setted?

Comment: The folder contains files » Macros are enabled » Printer is installed and stetted to PDF printer. About the references: What specific references should I add?